# How Can I Transform an Ed25519KeyHash into a BaseAddress with the Cardano Serialization Library

Tags: plutus

I am currently attempting to transform a Ed25519KeyHash into a BaseAddress so I can use that address to perform transactions with the cardano-serialization-lib. However, I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

I managed to get a StakeCredential by doing:

StakeCredential.from_keyhash(  Ed25519KeyHash  instance  )

But I cannot find a way to get the BaseAddress. Has anyone figured out a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt this would be possible. As its name suggest, Ed25519KeyHash is a signature provided through a cryptographic hash of the initial key. Such a process is not reversible and is not intended to be.
I don't know the use case but if you need the initial address the hash comes from, you have to provide it another way.